# Starting of ActiveMQ on Mac OS X ends with exception

Tags: java, macos, activemq-classic

I installed ActiveMQ 5.9.0 thru homebrew, but when I try to start activemq by 'bin/activemq console' it's end up with following exception:

```
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:137)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:146)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:41)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 22 more
ERROR: java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:137)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not load xbean factory:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:146)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBrokerFactoryHandler(BrokerFactory.java:41)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ is that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jar is missing containing the class `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource` in the activeMQ lib.

Comment: It's in lib/optional/spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: At least on linux the start script does not put anything in lib/optional on the classpath.

Comment: Do you have this lib at apache-activemq-5.5.0/lib/optional folder